Unable to sign out the user from Bot composer framework - Why not working
I have implemented the OAuth Input Login using bot composer framework dialog. Login function is working as expected. But based on my requirement, I will have log out the user which ever is logged in.

I am passing user id along with connection name at run time but still but it's not working.
Please suggest, why it not working and if I am doing any mistake.

If you use =user.id or UserId, does it work?

I have used the =user.id also.. I am trying to pass unique GUID received from AD Graph. but still not working.

Can you explain more about "I am trying to pass unique GUID received from AD Graph."? Where are you doing that?
